# Not able to access object inside array in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

I wish to access object inside an array a sample format of the array is given below,

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 3
            [adminid] => 1
            [payment_value] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user_id] => 3
            [adminid] => 2
            [payment_value] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [user_id] => 4
            [adminid] => 3
            [payment_value] => 
        )
)
```

From the array above i wish to fetch all the user_id , in this array it will be :

```
3
3
4
```

But as you can see that in the 2 objects the value of user_id is same so in this case i would like to filter further and take only 1 value , so the final result that i want from the array should be

```
3
4
```

I don't know how to eliminate duplicate values however the code that i am trying to use to get the first part is

```
print_r($rdata) // this gives the above sample array

foreach ($rdata as $key) 
    {
        $userid = $key->user_id;

        $this->db->where('id',$userid);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

By using the above code i am just getting the value 3 as result, however i want 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

```
$data_collection = [
        (object)[
            "id" => 1,
            "user_id" => 3,
            "adminid" => 1,
            "payment_value" =>""
        ],
        (object)[
            "id" => 2,
            "user_id" => 3,
            "adminid" => 2,
            "payment_value" =>""
        ],
        (object)[
            "id" => 3,
            "user_id" => 4,
            "adminid" => 3,
            "payment_value" =>""
        ]
];

$user_id= [];
$i=0;
foreach ($data_collection as $single_data) {
    $user_id[$i]= $single_data->user_id;
    $i++;
}
$user_id = array_unique($user_id);
/**
 * I don't knwo what this code does to you
 */
$data_to_be_returned = [];
foreach ($user_id as $single_user_id) {
    $this->db->where('id',$single_user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('user');
    $data_to_be_returned = [$single_user_id => $query->result()];
}
```

You can't return in foreach loop